# "By some at least of the merchants" — what does this syntax mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> The thirteenth century also witnessed the adoption of armorial devices by ***some at least of the merchants***.
>   — (Goodall, John A.., Heraldry in Italy During the Middle Ages and Renaissance, Coat of Arms, No. 37, January 1959.)

What does "some at least of the merchants" mean? Does it mean "at least some merchants had adopted coats of arms"? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: I wonder if we aren't overlooking the possibility of poor copy editing here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would find this sentence more commonly like

> The thirteenth century also witnessed the adoption of armorial devices by at least some of the merchants.

The writer indicates that there is evidence that some merchants adopted armorial devices, but (I guess since 13th century documentation is usually far from complete) there is no reason to assume that it might not have been more common.

So (at least some of) the merchants had adopted them.

As to the inversion, I guess it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. You could read a comma in there as follows :

"some, at least, of the the merchants".

So the meaning is some, but not all, of the merchants had adopted coats of arms.